# Ubuntu 12.04 + supervisord service - not starting with the system

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I installed `supervisord` on some of virtual machines that I manage and I also added init script for supervisor from here: https://github.com/Supervisor/initscripts/blob/master/ubuntu

Here is part of ansible role that is taking care of that:

```
- name: Install supervisord
  pip: name=supervisor state=present
  sudo: yes

- name: Create /etc/supervisor.d/ directory
  file: path=/etc/supervisor.d/ state=directory
  sudo: yes

- name: Create /var/log/supervisor/ directory
  file: path=/var/log/supervisor state=directory
  sudo: yes

- name: Copy supervisor global configuration
  copy: src=supervisord.conf dest=/etc/supervisord.conf
  sudo: yes  

- name: Copy supervisor service script
  copy: src=supervisord_init dest=/etc/init.d/supervisord mode=0755
  sudo: yes
  register: supervisord_init

- name: Invoke update-rc.d for supervisord
  command: update-rc.d supervisord defaults
  sudo: yes
```

now I observed that after rebooting the system `supervisord` service is not started as it should be.

When I manually invoke init script service starts fine:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/supervisord start
Starting supervisor: supervisord.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Is there some place (maybe particular log file) where system would write which services it is trying to start during booting?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I don't know why but after I fixed my `nginx` configuration and after I reinstalled `supervisord` everything works fine.